# Jar с вложенными изображениями

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, icon

Мне нужно получить jar файл с работающей кастомной иконкой самого приложения.

Собираю через `Export/Java/Runnable Jar file`. При запуске через Eclipse все работает без нареканий, но вот уже собранный jar отказывается работать при присутствующей строке - `frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("images\\icon.png")));`

Если ее убрать все работает. Сам файл иконки работе не мешает(не замечено).

Comment: А ты открой джарник ручками и посмотри, есть ли эта png в папке, в которой лежит скомпилированный класс ( на который у тебя this ссылается). Уверен, что нет. И скорее всего это дело в том, как собирает jar'ник eclipse. Но на счет последнего могу ошибаться

Comment: Забыл уточнить, иконка попадает в архив, я проверял, в обоих случаях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло такое решение, обвернутое в try-catch:

```
frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/icon.png")));
```

Иконка находится по пути `resources/images` из корня проекта.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте вот такой код:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/icon.png")
```

Comment: А что изменится? Внутри Eclipse и мой код ставит иконку и приложение нормально работает. При экспорте в jar не запускается, сомневаюсь что что-то изменится

Comment: ну если не хотите, не пробуйте =), а вы всегда результат проверяете интуитивно?

Comment: Проверил, даже NPE прилетает, соответственно проверить jar'ник не получится

Comment: Вы что-то делаете не так, код взят из рабочего приложения, где в продакшене ресурсы берутся именно из джарника

Comment: вот работоспособный пример https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_j8xtRlEFpEaHRBaV90SEZuMnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images\\icon.png")));

Так?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26967/discussion-between-konstantin-balashev-and--).

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26968/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and--).